# Map test data using sklearn TSNE

Tags: python, scikit-learn, transform, cluster-analysis

Is there a way to extract the mapping procedure in `sklearn.manifold.TSNE` in python so that you can map new data into the reduced dimensional space?

Importantly, I mean without having to retrain on the new data as well here.

For example say you trained a TSNE map as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
X = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
X_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform(X)
```

As seen in the documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html

Can you extract the transformation so that you can map new data into the same space:

```
Y = np.array([[0, 0.8, 0.8], [0.1, 0, 1], [1.2, 0.2, 1], [1, 1.1, 1]])
```

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: don't think you'll be able to save using the TSNE in sklearn, try searching for 'parametric t-sne', i think there are ones that are implemented in tensorflow.
https://github.com/jsilter/parametric_tsne

Comment: I didn't think so, it seemed like something that would have had an easy answer available before I came to ask it :) Thanks I'll try using that!

Comment: On a side note, would this be possible for sklearn.manifold.PCA or is it the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

tSNE is a non-linear, non-parametric embedding.

So there is no "closed form" way of updating it with new points. Even worse: adding new points may require existing points to move.

Because of this, making tSNE apply to new data will require substantial changes to the method, it won't be the original tSNE anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Parametric t-SNE has option to apply on the test data but this is not available in Sklearn. [Reference issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5361).

Having set this we have mention that it is implemented in other place [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5361#issuecomment-226747171)